# Win32Exception was unhandled when switching tabs, in form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, winapi, panel, tabcontrol

I have a form with a tabcontrol, the tabscontrol starts with a single tab and more are added dynamically if need be. Each tab holds around 20 seperate panels which are used to represent pages. It can handle 12 tabs fine and continue adding more way past 40. However, whenever you click on a tab to load it up it throws this error.

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.

With no location in the code to wear it crashed.

I've tried this on multiple machines and the same thing happens.

This is the code to adding a new tab.

```
    Public Sub CreateAnotherPage5(NoOfPage5 As Integer)
          For i = 1 To NoOfPage5
           Dim PG5E As New ConditionReportPage5
           Dim PREV As ConditionReportPage5

            If NoOfPages Mod 20 = 0 Then
                Dim NwTabPG As New TabPage
                Dim NwPanel As New PanelAutoScroll
                NoOfTabs = NoOfTabs + 1
                NwTabPG.Name = "tpg_" & NoOfTabs
                NwPanel.Name = "pnl_" & NoOfTabs
                NwTabPG.Text = NoOfTabs
                NwPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                NwPanel.AutoScroll = True
                frm_Main.tbc_Main.TabPages.Add(NwTabPG)
                NwTabPG.Controls.Add(NwPanel)
                PG5E.Location = New Point(frm_Main.FirstPageX, frm_Main.FirstPageY)
                NwPanel.Controls.Add(PG5E)
                NoOfPages = 1
            Else
                Dim PrevPanl As PanelAutoScroll
                Dim PrevTabPG As TabPage
                PrevTabPG = frm_Main.tbc_Main.Controls.Item("tpg_" & NoOfTabs)
                PrevPanl = PrevTabPG.Controls.Item("pnl_" & NoOfTabs)
                PREV = TryCast(PrevPanl.Controls(NoOfPages - 1), ConditionReportPage5)
                PG5E.Location = New Point(frm_Main.FirstPageX, Math.Abs(PREV.Location.Y + 1000))
                PrevPanl.Controls.Add(PG5E)
                NoOfPages = NoOfPages + 1
            End If
            ExtensionConfig.DoubleBuffer(PG5E, True)
            PG5E.SetNewDef()
            PG5E.PageNo = NoOfPages
     End sub
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The actual exception message would help.

Comment: The option to *"Break when this exception type is thrown"* will produce the entire call stack. You need to enable it.

Comment: I ticked the "Break when this exception type is thrown" and tested a couple times and it seems to "SOMETIMES" crash on "NwPanel.Controls.Add(PG5E)". Hope this helps

Comment: That's not a call stack.